# Total time calculation in a sql query for a day where time in 24 hour format as hhmm

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with date(date), left time(varchar2(4)) and arrival time(varchar2(4)). Time taken is in 24 hour format as hhmm. If a person travel 3 times a day, what will be the query to calculate total travel time in a day?
I am using oracle 11g. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Pls post your query

Comment: Why are you using varchar columns? Doesn't Oracle have any time/interval data types?

Comment: What happens if a journey goes over midnight - so the arrival 'time' is earlier than the lest 'time'? Why aren't you just storing both left and arrival as data type `date`?

Comment: @jarlh Using interval types is complicated when you probably want to be able to display the time like `12:34` rather than `+00 12:34:00.000000`.  But as Alex says, `date` makes more sense than `varchar2`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value to a number and report in minutes:

```
select to_number(substring(time, 1, 2))*60 + to_number(substring(time, 3, 2)) as minutes
```

Your query would look something like:

```
select person, sum(to_number(substring(time, 1, 2))*60 + to_number(substring(time, 3, 2))) as minutes
from t
group by person;
```

I see no reason to convert this back to a string -- or to even store the value as a string instead of as a number.  But if you need to, you can reverse the process to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 answers, If you want to sum time only on date then it can be done as:-

```
select curr_date,
sum(24 * (to_date(arrival_time, 'HH24:mi:ss')- to_date(left_time, 'HH24:mi:ss'))) as difference 
from sql_prac group by curr_date,arrival_time,left_time;
```

The sample output is as follows:-

```
select curr_date,left_time,arrival_time from sql_prac;

CURR_DATE LEFT_TIME            ARRIVAL_TIME       
--------- -------------------- --------------------
30-JUN-17 00:00:00             15:00:00             
30-JUL-17 03:30:00             11:30:00             
30-AUG-17 03:00:00             12:30:00             
30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
30-JUN-17 00:00:00             15:00:00             
30-JUL-17 03:30:00             11:30:00             
30-AUG-17 03:00:00             12:30:00             
30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00
```

9 rows selected

```
select curr_date,sum(24 * (to_date(arrival_time, 'HH24:mi:ss')- to_date(left_time, 'HH24:mi:ss'))) as difference 
from sql_prac group by curr_date,arrival_time,left_time;

CURR_DATE DIFFERENCE
--------- ----------
30-JUN-17         30 
30-JUL-17         16 
30-SEP-17         39 
30-AUG-17         19
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to sum it by person and date then it can be done as:-**

```
    select dept,curr_date,sum(24 * (to_date(arrival_time, 'HH24:mi:ss')- to_date(left_time, 'HH24:mi:ss'))) as difference 
from sql_prac group by dept,curr_date,arrival_time,left_time order by Dept;
```

The sample output is as follows:-

1. Data in table is:-

   select dept,curr_date,left_time,arrival_time from sql_prac;

> DEPT                 CURR_DATE LEFT_TIME            ARRIVAL_TIME
>
> ```
> -------------------- --------- -------------------- --------------------
> A                    30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
> B                    30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
> C                    30-AUG-17 03:00:00             12:30:00             
> D                    30-DEC-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
> A                    30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
> B                    30-JUL-17 03:30:00             11:30:00             
> C                    30-AUG-17 03:00:00             12:30:00             
> D                    30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00             
> R                    30-SEP-17 04:00:00             17:00:00
> ```

2. Data fetched using the query

   select dept,curr_date,sum(24 * (to_date(arrival_time, 'HH24:mi:ss')- to_date(left_time, 'HH24:mi:ss'))) as difference 
   from sql_prac group by dept,curr_date,arrival_time,left_time order by Dept;

> ```
>     DEPT                 CURR_DATE DIFFERENCE
> -------------------- --------- ----------
> A                    30-SEP-17         26 
> B                    30-JUL-17          8 
> B                    30-SEP-17         13 
> C                    30-AUG-17         19 
> D                    30-SEP-17         13 
> D                    30-DEC-17         13 
> R                    30-SEP-17         13
> ```